# JSP <a href=" ">is not able to hold regular statement

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am creating a web application with header containing a menu bar which contains 2 level of children.Now as part of second requirement I am creating a breadcrumb, as part of that I am trying to show the user where they are in the application.For that,I thought to use the URL itself and just show it on the UI,where each hyperlink will be separated by forward slash("/").

part of index.jsp where I am writing from the java code to jsp

```
out.println("<li><a  href=result?id="+keyinner+"/"+key+"/"+secKey+"/"+**innerhashMap.get(keyinner)**+"><span>"+innerhashMap.get(keyinner)+"</span></a></li>");
```

`innerhashMap.get(keyinner)` gives the last vertical menu bar as shown in the image.I want to have the complete string which is selected in the bold part of href but only first letter is coming up.I don't find any reason for that.Could you please help me out

Thanks in advance

[Menu Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKmc9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the quotation marks for href="". Without them, your href will break off at the first space.

```
out.println("<li><a  href=\"result?id="+...+"\">.....");
```

Also, if your text contains < or > symbols, you need to convert those to the HTML entities, &lt; and &gt;.  Otherwise, a text like <hello> will be treated like an HTML tag (and become invisible) rather than display as text.